# Networking interface for beginners

Tags: linux, networking

I am currently learning network interfaces.

Below, using netstat, I listed interfaces with respective ports:

[image]

**True or False**

Please correct if wrong. If I were to translate this in my own words it would go like this:

1. Anyone with `ipv4` and `ipv6` address can connect to my host via `SSH`
2. Anyone with `ipv6` address can connect to my host via `http` through port `80`
3. No one with `ipv4` address can connect to my host via `http`

**Question**

Why is `smtp` bound to `localhost`? My understanding was that a mail server should be accessible to the outside world so computers can communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email daemon only listens to localhost because in this case, it only receives emails to send outside from services running on this localhost and is not serving any other machines, *at least directly*.

The tenet here is the old Unix principle of the running the minimal services needed as usually email daemons/services are ripe for abuse from hackers and malware alike.

I would not be surprised that is the default configuration, and if you want to serve other machines, you have to modify it and incur the risks if it is badly configured.

Bear in mind the email daemon is still capable of *sending emails to the outside world*. Having the service bound to localhost just means it only receives emails from another service running in the same server.